# How to find the current status of a PayPal recurring payment from the response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal

I'm working on an application using the `paypal-sdk-rest` gem found here: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK

When status is changed, PayPal sends an HTTP Post message to a controller on my server. I made this controller save the response so I could it.

This is what was passed:

```
{
"payment_cycle":"Monthly",
"txn_type":"recurring_payment_profile_created",
"last_name":"name of the buyer",
"next_payment_date":"03:00:00 Sep 23, 2015 PDT",
"residence_country":"BR",
"initial_payment_amount":"0.00",
"currency_code":"BRL",
"time_created":"06:56:01 Sep 23, 2015 PDT",
"verify_sign":"a long code",
"period_type":" Regular",
"payer_status":"unverified",
"tax":"0.00",
"payer_email":"an email",
"first_name":"the name",
"receiver_email":"an email",
"payer_id":"a short code",
"product_type":"1",
"shipping":"0.00",
"amount_per_cycle":"25.00",
"profile_status":"Active",
"charset":"windows-1252",
"notify_version":"3.8",
"amount":"25.00",
"outstanding_balance":"0.00",
"recurring_payment_id":"a short code",
"product_name":"Prata",
"ipn_track_id":"a short  code",
"controller":"notifications",
"action":"create"
}
```

I have to check the status of this payment, and update on my server. I need to know if it was approved, if it is pending for some reason or rejected.

How do I know the payment status?

Obs: what is the difference from payer_status to profile_status in this response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Payer status indicates if the account holder was verified by PayPal. Profile status means the status of the profile. A status of Active means the profile was created and it is currently active.

From the PayPal Developer [Handling Recurring Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/digital-goods/ECDGRecurringPayments/#id08652E00HL7) documentation:

> The recurring payments actions you may take depend on the status of
>   the profile.
>
> A recurring payments profile can have one of the following status
>   values:
>
> ```
> ActiveProfile
> PendingProfile
> ExpiredProfile
> SuspendedProfile
> CancelledProfile
> ```
>
> If PayPal successfully creates the profile, the profile has an
>   **ActiveProfile** status. However, if a non-recurring initial payment
>   fails and you set **FAILEDINITAMTACTION** to **CancelOnFailure** in the
>   **CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile** request, PayPal creates the profile
>   with a status of **PendingProfile**. The profile remains in this status
>   until the initial payment either completes successfully or fails.
>
> A profile has a status of **ExpiredProfile** when PayPal completes the
>   total billing cycles for the optional trial and the regular payment
>   periods.

You can use [GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) API call to get the details of the payment profile. It will tell you if the transaction was successful and the next billing date.

Answer (score -1):

```
response = PayPal::Recurring.new(profile_id: "I-VCEL6TRG35CU").send(:profile)

response.status
```

It will return :active, :canceled like this.